# When I will suggest edit question or answer

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Whenever I trying to edit any question or answer I will getting the below warning/error

> Suggested Edits You are temporarily banned from suggesting edits -
>   please review your edit history.

Can anyone tell me why it is happened and when I will suggest the edit again?

Comment: Looking over some of your edits, I notice you use quote-formatting for things that are not quoted, code-formatting for things that are not code etc. The sad thing is that too much of those suggestions got accepted...

Comment: As explained in the comment above and the answer, bad edits was probably the reason and in order to avoid it you should follow the [guidelines of editing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) and not make the same mistakes again and again and again

Comment: @AlonEitan yes I got it. but can you please tell me when stackoverflow will remove this temparary ban.

Comment: @Narayan No, only moderators can answer that :)

Comment: Your ban will be lifted in 4 days. Please use this time to go through some of [the edits you've suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1969866/narayan?tab=activity) and consider whether they were really good edits. If you have questions, please ask on Meta.

Comment: @CodyGray Yes I will thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [activity tab on your profile on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1969866/narayan?tab=activity) shows a [rejected edit suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17005992) two days ago [and](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16966904) [another](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16966804) [three](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16966799) on August 8th. There are still more further back.

I suspect you can get more information by reviewing those parts of your profile which are only visible to you.